# How to create a single message from a list in Python?

Tags: python

**I have a list like this:**

```
["Hello", "World"]
```

if I write this code it mass prints the values ​​inside it

```
data = ["Hello", "World"]

for x in data:
   print(x)
```

**giving me the answer:**

```
Hello
World
```

Instead, I would like to receive a single output, because if I use the same method for messaging applications or other third-party services, it will spam me with messages.

I would expect a single response, as if it were a single sentence, adding \n to go to a new line, but everything located in a single print message

**Thanks in advance for your help**

Comment: `print(*data)` or even `print(' '.join(data))`. If you are using for loop, consider `print(x, end = ' ')`